# How Do I Transplant and Execute User Code in a C# Source Generator?

Tags: c#, roslyn, expression-trees, sourcegenerators, csharpscript

I am creating a Roslyn .NET source generator. With it I am inspecting **user code** for lambda expressions given as an argument in a method call like this:

```cs
// User Code
MyLibrary.MyMethod<Guid>(k => $"alfa/{k.SomeMethod()}");
```

I want to, within my source generator at compile-time, take the `LambdaExpressionSyntax` node `k => $"alfa/{k.SomeMethod()}"` and transplant it to some simple code I will **generate and run** to interrogate it for e.g. its run-time expression tree shape or call its `.ToString()` method:

```cs
// Generated Code
using System;
using Etc;
Expression<Func<Guid, string>> expression = k => $"alfa/{k.SomeMethod()}";
return expression;
```

I have so far discovered the `CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync()` method, which seems like the easiest way to compile and execute the code.

Unfortunately, this (and probably any) approach requires me to sus out what the dependencies are of the expression I am trying to transplant, so that I can generate the appropriate `using` statements and add the required library references to the compilation.

For example, `SomeMethod()` above is an extension method that lives in a separate class library from the inspected user code. Its namespace and class library will need to be included in the `using`s and compilation references.

Supposing I have a magic method to get the referenced types, what I have so far is something like this:

```cs
var referencedTypes = GetReferencedTypes(lambdaExpressionSyntax);

var result = CSharpScript
    .EvaluateAsync(
        code,
        ScriptOptions.Default
            .AddReferences(
                typeof(Func<,>).Assembly,
                typeof(Expression).Assembly)
            .AddReferences(referencedTypes
                .Select(t => t.ContainingAssembly.GetMetadata().GetReference())
                .ToArray()))
    .Result;
```

Unfortunately the way I am trying to add the references does not appear to work. I get an error at runtime that the assembly could not be found.

So my questions are:

1. How do I correctly determine all of the dependencies for a given `LambdaExpressionSyntax`?
2. How do I properly add references to those dependencies when calling `CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync()`?
3. Is there a better or simpler way of achieving what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve the above pretty simply once I realized that the `using` directives and references needed for the transplanted code *must be a subset of* the user code I am transplanting from. So the relevant section of my source generator's `Execute` method has become:

```cs
var code = $$"""
    Expression<Func<{{keyType.Name}}, string>> expr = {{lambdaExpression}};
    return expr;
    """;

var imports = lambdaExpression.SyntaxTree
    .GetRoot()
    .DescendantNodes()
    .OfType<UsingDirectiveSyntax>()
    .Select(u => u.Name.ToString())
    .Append("System")
    .Append("System.Linq.Expressions")
    .Append(keyType.ContainingNamespace.ToString())
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(u => u)
    .ToList();

var options = ScriptOptions.Default
    .AddReferences(
        typeof(Func<,>).Assembly,
        typeof(Expression).Assembly)
    .AddReferences(
        compilation.References)
    .AddImports(imports);

var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(code, options);
```

Critically, I give the `AddReferences` and `AddImports` methods the values derived from the user code's syntax tree and compilation.

This still will not work if the transplanted user code references e.g. a local variable or class member. These are not supported use cases for my efforts, so I will likely just add graceful error handling for these occasions.

Comment: I tried your solution and it seems to work when it comes to just dotnet build but for some reason I didn't managed to make Visual Studio to generate files when using the CSharpScript. Running the application works but in VS I still get errors saying the generated coded doesnt exist. Did you have similar problem?